# Getting issue while build my application for Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the Angular 2 version. I used to install the bootstrap through `node.js` command prompt.

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

and I added the .csproj like this. This is to deploy my application on the server through octopus, but I am getting this issue while building my solution on a local machine.

> Error: The command "npm install ngx-bootstrap --save" exited with code
>   1.

**Packages.json:**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "mywizard-ad",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build-Debug": "webpack --config webpack.debug.js --env.WebApiEnv dev",
    "build-Release": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env.WebApiEnv dev",
    "build-Prod": "webpack  --config webpack.prod.js --env.WebApiEnv prod",
    "build-Stage": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env.WebApiEnv stage",
    "build-UAT": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env.WebApiEnv uat",
    "build-Preprod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env.WebApiEnv preprod",
    "build-Prod_EU": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env.WebApiEnv prod_eu",
    "build-Stage_EU": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env.WebApiEnv stage_eu",
    "build-Hotfix": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js --env.WebApiEnv hotfix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-simple-global": "^1.2.5",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-simple-global": "^1.2.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.5.6",
    "webpack-concat-plugin": "^1.4.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

Comment: Please paste your package.json

Comment: Is there no other errors output?

Comment: no, it's pointing to my .csproj

Comment: Sorry, I did not get the point. What is pointing to `my.csproj`?

Comment: D:\Builds\87\828\Sources\4577_MywizardAD\4577_MyWizardAD.csproj (664): The command "npm install ngx-bootstrap --save" exited with code 1.          this is exactly am getting

Comment: Maybe, there are some conflicts in your project, though I am not sure. I assume you have all your dependencies in `package.json`. If so, you can delete the folder `node_modules` and try `npm install` to reinstall them. The output might indicate if there some issues in the dependencies or not.

Comment: I tried to reinstall also, but it's not working. if I comment this line and doing the build, it's working fine but while uncomment, it's not working.   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm install --save angular2-moment" />
    <Exec Command="npm install angular2-uuid --saveff " />
    <Exec Command="npm install ngx-bootstrap --save" />
</Target>

Comment: Okay, great! Now, you know why your build was failing. It is not an issue related to `npm`.

Comment: yeah, but this should be need while deploying the code to server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157277/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-lawrence).

Comment: angular2 or 4? "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.1", and "I am using anguar2 version"

Comment: I am using Angular 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not related to `npm` but to your settings in `my.csproj` file. Actually you don't need to use this file to install your `npm modules`. The `.csproj` file is used by Visual Studio to organize your project. So there is no need from your part to edit them for your dependencies.

The `npm` flag `--save` will save the module as a dependency in your `package.json`. It is useful when you `git clone` the project. After cloning the project, `npm install` will install all the packages that you have installed previously with the flag `--save`. You don't need to have those lines in your .csproj file, especially if they make your `npm install` fail.

You can try this:

- Comment the lines in your `my.csproj` file
- Run manually the command locally (you can check that you will have an entry corresponding to those dependencies in your "package.json"; if they are already there, it means that all the dependencies are already installed, i.e you can skip this step)
- Commit your new "package.json" file